# How to disable properties of external css class and use internal css class with same name but different property in html

Tags: html, css

i have declared a class in my external style sheet and i have also declared the class with same name in internal css but the internal class has only one properties and external class has many other properties so how can i only use the some properties of internal style sheet and not use the any properties of external style sheet class ihave used the style scoped properties of css but it only working on mozila

```
My external class

    #portfolio-wrapper li {
    border: 10px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    /* display: inline-block; */
    list-style: none outside none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 10px;}

My internal class
#portfolio-wrapper li {
width: 160px;
}
```

Comment: what are the properties you don't want to have?

Comment: I only want the width properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable them. you can neutralise them in your own css. Of cause you have to set your own values for those properties. Because what I done below is just set them to 0, maybe you want to have margins and border.

```
/* not sure if this is your ul? */
#portfolio-wrapper {
    padding-left: 20px; /* what fits your design */
}

#portfolio-wrapper li {
    width: 160px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
    list-style: circle !important; /* updated */
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: please tell me one more thing how to show dots with li

Comment: yes i have used this code but i am not able to see any dots.

Comment: do you have the padding turned off on the ul ?

Comment: Sorry but it didn't works i think some other class of external css is causing this problem so please tell me what i have to do to get the dots with li

Comment: now i have written all the code in inline style for li and when i am giving the padding the text goes left but dots is not displaying

Comment: this is my link http://www.emobitechnologies.com/webapplicationportfolio.php when on the mouseover on image some text is displaying i want that before the text dots should come

Comment: now i am able to see dot in mozila but not in other browser

Comment: @akhilesh at first glance I can't find anything. Just a tip though. Why have circles there? Design wise looks better not to.

Comment: when you will open the page then you will see small small images and when you will take tour mouse on the image then you will some text but the text is coming starting by dots in mozila but not coming in any other browser

Comment: @akhilesh You mean this dots? http://screencast.com/t/tG6Qxgfc I'm checking all browsers and they show up. Maybe you should empty your cache.

Comment: I have used &bull to show the bullet and now it's working fine